# Is there way to make a thread come out of an infinite semaphore wait when the process is killed?

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, semaphore, freeze

OS: Windows.
Language : C

I have a thread that sends a request over TCP to a server and waits infinitely on semaphore for response. There is another thread that reads the socket, copies the received data in a common buffer and pulses the semaphore to come out of the wait. All this works fine. But in a case where the process is killed for some reason, the thread waiting on semaphore waits for ever while other threads terminate.

Why doesn't the thread waiting semaphore end when process is killed? I read in Linux forums that there is SEM_UNDO which helps in this type of situations. Is there something similar on Windows? any workaround?

Comment: How have you created your thread _beginthread or _beginthreadex?

Comment: Simply have the other process create the semaphore instead.  So you get WAIT_ABANDONED when killing the process destroys it.

Comment: @HansPassant - there must be something else going on.  Windows does not care what state a thread is in when a process is terminated - all the threads in the process are stopped.  MSDN says: 'If a thread is waiting on a kernel object, it will not be terminated until the wait has completed. This can cause the application to hang.' Empirically, on every Windows since W95, this is just not correct - threads waiting on semaphores do not prevent an app from shutting down itself, (ExitProcess), or being terminated, (TerminateProcess).

Comment: @Martin - There's nothing nice about Exit/TerminateProcess, threads get killed without recourse.  Visible in any C or C++ program, it ends when the main() function returns, regardless of threads.

Comment: @HansPassant - right, so why is the OP having this problem?  Why will the OP process not terminate?

Comment: @Martin - he's talking about killing the *other process*, not his own.

Comment: @HansPassant - Oh?  What other process - the server?  I'm really confused now.  Maybe I need more coffee this morning - I had two urgent 'need fix in the next hour' calls before I could put the kettle on today :(

Comment: Ah, I get it now! Server is terminated and client is hang, and the problem is how can client detect that server does not exist.

Comment: If the server is killed and so does not have a chance to perform the 4-way close handshake, the client may never know unless it tries to send something.  There is a 'keepalive' option on sockets, but the timeout on this is usually very long and system-wide, so not much help.  The usual way round this is to poll at application-level. In your case, you could time out on the semaphore wait and send some message to be echoed by the server.  If the semaphore wait times out again because the server has not replied, you can assume the server is dead.

Comment: @Shashi: we're confused.  Please clarify your question.  Is the thread that is hanging in the process that is being killed?  If so, how is the process being killed?  Does the process actually appear to have been successfully killed, or is it hanging?

Comment: @Martin: I think the situation MSDN is describing occurs when the process is waiting from kernel-mode, not when it is waiting in user-mode on a kernel object.  I think in practice this only ever results in a very short delay.

Comment: Yes, the thread hanging is in the same process that is being killed. Process is being killed through Windows Task Manager or Process Explorer. The process does not end, it just sits there.

Comment: @MartinJames: I have some implemented a workaround something similar to what you suggested. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

[Semaphores do not have owners](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/11/23/496248.aspx). If you wait on a semaphore, then you are waiting for *anybody* to signal it. There is no way to declare "It's this guy's responsibility to signal the semaphore, and if he terminates without signaling it, then I should do something to recover."

If you want an owner-trackable synchronization object, use a mutex. Alternatively, you can have the waiter also wait on the other process handle and perform recovery when it detects that the other process has terminated.

Comment: The thread that is hanging has no way to find out if the server is active or not. Windows should have ended the hanging thread when the process is being killed. I see no point in keeping the thread running.

Comment: The thread will wake up if anybody (not just the thread that got killed) signals the semaphore. Windows cannot predict the future and say "I predict that nobody will ever signal this semaphore" so it keeps waiting just in case. If you want ownership semantics, then use a mutex.

Answer (score 2):

When a process is terminated (as with [TerminateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686714%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) then all threads within this process are terminated as well. There are no exceptions. This is how the system works. If some thread is still alive then that automatically means that its process is alive as well. So, what you see is different from what you think you are seeing. To verify that process is really "killed" (or terminated in Windows world) use Task Manager and Processes tab.

Comment: Yes.  I have loads of multithreaded apps deployed on Windows OS for decades.  I use message-passing designs based on producer-consumer queues - the threads wait on a semaphore in the queue class, usually with INFINITE timeout.  When I, or my customers, click on the 'Close' icon, the whole app shuts down immediately without any need to explicitly signal, destroy or otherwise fiddle with any of the semaphores.

Comment: I believe in your application there is a "Close" event handler that close the application gracefully. But in my case the process is being killed via Windows Task Manager. So there is no graceful closure.

Comment: @Shashi, There is a difference if application is closed from Applications tab and from Processes tab. When closing app from Applications tab Task Manager first tries all the nice ways to close the app. When closing app from Processes tab Task Manager immediately calls TerminateProcess.

Comment: Yes. Thanks all for your responses.